# ssrs multivalued parameter that selects which reports to execute

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

In an SSRS 2008 report, I would like to be able to allow the user the option of selecting between 1 to 30 different ssrs reports that they would like to run as a parameter value.  Basically when the main report starts to run, I would like to allow the user the option to pick which report(s) they would like to run as a multivalued parameter. This would be different than a user clicking on a link that would call a subreport or click on a link that would call a different report.

Can you tell me if the above option is possible in SSRS 2008? If so, can you tell me how to accomplish this goal? If this is not possible, can you make any recommendations on other possible options on how users can select which report(s) will run and tell me how to set this up in SSRS 2008?

If this option is not available in ssrs 2008, is it an option in SSRTS 2012? If so, can you tell me how to make the multiple report selection option a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to go about it.

```
1. Create a main report with you multi-value that has values A and B.
2. Create a sub report that contains Report A and B as sub reports with a parameter that accepts multi-value.
3. Perform rendering logic created in step 2.
```

Comment: Are you saying in the main report that I have multivalue parameter that allows the user to select report A, B, C, and so on? Then pass the same multivalued parameter to each subreport that is needed? Then only the subreports that were selected will be displayed on the particular execution run? The subreport visibility would be based upon the multivalue parameter that is passed?

Comment: Yes, however, you could plop all your reports on the main report as a sub-reports. That would also work. As LeSteelBox points out, you can create a dataset with a query set to SELECT (1=1) then place the sub-reports in a separate header for the dataset. The you can hide or show each row visibility based on your parameters.

Comment: questions: 1. What would be the differences of placing all the subreports on the main report or having the number of tables or matrixes on the main report equal to the number of subreports? What method is better and why? 2. what does SELECT (1=1) mean in sql?

Comment: 1. A matrix and table adjust widths based on content while other controls do not. 2. Select 1=1 always returns one record. If you have a table or matrix that needs to print at least one record and requires a datasource then setting the datasets expression to 1=1 will satisfy those needs.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you decide to use sub-reports or a group of tables you can display or hide them by adding an IIF expression in each tablix's (or subreport's) visibility properties.

```
=IIF(Parameter!ReportOption.Value=1, FALSE, TRUE)
```

...where ReportOption is the parameter your user clicks on to choose which report they want to see. Add this parameter by going to the Report Parameter Properties and entering your list of reports (via Available Values).

Example

Label: Report XYZ  | Value: 1
Label: Report ABC  | Value: 2

Side note: If you decide to add a table for each report you'll need to add its respective datasets/datasources.

Hope this helps.